# Build correct schema sql in cubejs

Tags: javascript, postgresql, database-schema, cube.js

I have a Postgres table like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b39a248ac9dde6400795e8a236e58d02  and it works as expected. but when i use that sql query into cubejs seem it work to slow or some time can not load .

```
cube(`State`, {
    rewriteQueries: false,
    sql: `WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            id,
        timestamp,
        machineid,
        state,
        next_state,
            start_time,
            end_time,
            
            gs,
            lag(gs) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY gs)                                 
        FROM
            (
       SELECT
        DISTINCT timestamp,
        id,
        machineid,
        timestamp as start_time,
        state,
        lead("timestamp",1,timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY machineid ORDER BY timestamp) as end_time,
        lead("state",1,state) OVER (PARTITION BY machineid ORDER BY timestamp) as next_state 
          FROM mstate WHERE ${FILTER_PARAMS.Machine.machineid.filter('machineid')}
          
       ) a
        LEFT JOIN LATERAL
            generate_series(start_time::date + 1, end_time::date, interval '1 day') gs  
        ON TRUE
    )
    SELECT                                                                             
        id,
        timestamp,
        machineid,
        state,
        next_state,
        COALESCE(lag, start_time) AS start_time,
        gs - interval '1 second' AS next_time
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE gs IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)                                                           
        id,
        timestamp,
        machineid,
        state,
        next_state,
        CASE WHEN start_time::date = end_time::date THEN start_time ELSE end_time::date END,  
        end_time
    FROM
        cte 
        ORDER BY start_time ASC`,
    
    
    
});
```

can you help me build right schema sql in Cubejs for it works as expected like origin query in link ?